# NextJS router solution for react-router Switch statement?

Tags: react-router, next.js

For those using NextJS, how do you achieve the same behavior for react-router Switch behavior.

ie...

react-router

BASE PAGE

```
--- header
-------some sub content
-------<SWITCH>
           <Route .. for component 1 />
           <Route .. for component 2 />
           <Route .. for component 3 />
```

How is this achieved via NextJS?

Answer (score 3):

If your aim is to persist a layout across the whole app you could use next js [custom _app.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) to achieve that. As Next js is file-based routing, creating pages inside `pages/` will do the rest

Answer (score 0):

As its documentation says

> Next.js has a file-system based router built on the concept of pages.
> When a file is added to the pages directory it's automatically available as a route.
> The files inside the pages directory can be used to define most common patterns.

[index-routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction#index-routes)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired result by following these simple steps:

1. You have to put your route components in the pages folder like
   it's shown [here](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/navigate-between-pages/pages-in-nextjs)

> In Next.js, a page is a React Component exported from a file in the pages directory.

> Pages are associated with a route based on their filename. For example, in development:

- pages/index.js is associated with the / route.
- pages/posts/first-post.js is associated with the /posts/first-post route.

2. You have to add a Layout component so you can add general components like header to every route and wrap your pages with the layout component like it's shown [here](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/assets-metadata-css/layout-component) in Nextjs tutorial.

src/components/HOC/layout.js

```
export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <header>...</header>
      {children}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

pages/profile.js

```
import Layout from "../src/components/HOC/layout.js";

const Profile = (props) => (
  <Layout>
    <div>User's profile</div>
  </Layout>
);

export default Profile;
```

You can also add props like `title` to the layout component so you can change it for every specific route/page like below:

src/components/HOC/layout.js

```
export default function layout(Component, title) {
  return (props) => (
    <React.Fragment>
      <header>{title}</header>
      <Component {...props} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

pages/profile.js

```
import layout from '../src/components/HOC/layout.js'

const Profile = (userName) => <div>Profile of {userName}</div>;

export default layout(Profile,"Your Profile Page");
```

Comment: Stackoverflow answers should include code or explicit instructions, not generic text and links.  Please add code examples, especially since 1 is completely obtuse to your statement and what's in the link.  Also, I don't see how this answer has anything to do with the OP's question of using Switch or Switch-like behavior to change what component to render.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder but I don't think the links and text were generic at all. by the way, I added related quotes from the links and code examples in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Also, You can see in the code example and the previous quote how the answer relates to the question. Please, read the question's code and the code in my answer carefully, then you can see how they relate.

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for a solution to use React's `Switch` component.  But until I do, this is how I handle conditional switching:

```js
export default function Page({ page, pageType }) {

  // ...
  //

  switch (pageType) {
    case 1:
      return (
        <Layout>
          {beards.map((beard) => (
            <BeardedDeveloper {...beard} key={beard.id} />
          ))}
        </Layout>
      );
    case 2:
      return (
        <Layout>
          <BeardedDeveloperDetail {...beard} key={beard.id} />
        </Layout>
      );
  }
}

// for my use-case, `pageType` is defined in my `getStaticProps`
//
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {

  // ...
  //

  return {
    props: {
      page: page,
      pageType: pageType
    }
  };
}
```

It's an int; but, it can easily be changed to enum, string, or any defined type.